# Traducción en español para "muscle cars"

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

"Muscle cars" es un término que se usa para denominar a un cierto tipo de coche de tamaño medio, deportivo (incluso biplazas) y con potencia (fuerza, **músculo**). Suelen tener también un aspecto agresivo o llamativo. Pese a eso, no suelen ser coches caros (un Mercedes o un Cadillac son bonitos, potentes, etc. pero no son considerados *muscle cars* porque los precios no son tan asequibles).

Los *muscle cars* suelen ser coches norteamericanos como los *Mustang*, el *Camaro*, algunos modelos de *Dodge*, etc. (eso podría explicar en parte la falta de un término en español para referirse a estos coches. En ciertos países estos coches no abundan ya que no se fabrican o no se importan).

Como una imagen vale más que mil palabras (o mil links) aquí va una foto que le hice el otro día a un calendario de *muscle cars*.

[image]

¿Hay algún término en español para este tipo de coches? Conocí a alguien que tenía por hobby arreglar este tipo de coches. El otro día quería explicárselo en español a alguien y no encontré ningún término para describirlos.

Comment: Mientras buscamos alguna opción mejor, ¿qué tal "coche con [garra](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IvZfWwx)"? :D ("Garra": "Fuerza, empuje".)

Comment: La wikipedia tiene una entrada en español extensísima: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muscle_car Dice _Hoy en día, conocemos los muscle cars como coches de la época en la que la gasolina usaba plomo como antidetonante, y que tenían casi el mismo poder que un auto de carreras de la época_ y esto me hace pensar que es un término caído en desuso (ya mira más hacia atrás que hacia delante) y que por tanto tiene difícil que se adapte al español con una palabra propia si no se hizo ya.

Comment: @fedorqui pues entonces va a ser "deportivo _vintage_ americano" o "deportivo retro" (que, como dice Rompe Ralph, significa "viejo pero molón").

Comment: Yo no creo que tenga una traducción literal. Yo les digo "muscle cars", Igual que a las PC les digo "PC" y no "CP". Si la persona no sabe que son "muscle cars" ( o siguiendo mi ejemplo una "PC") igual le vas a tener que explicar. Pero no por eso deber inventar nuevas palabras.

Answer (score 3):

Al menos en España no se usa un término específico para ese tipo de coches, aparte de, coloquialmente, "esos monstruos americanos de los 60-70 que chupaban gasofa a lo bestia" ;)

Es verdad que se usa el término "*super coche*", directamente del inglés *supercar*, pero que yo sepa no se refiere al objeto de tu pregunta, sino a coches como Ferrari, Lamborghini, Porsche, McLaren; coches que valen una millonada y que en poco se diferencian de coches de carreras.
Supongo que también habría que mencionar el término "*gran turismo*", también un extranjerismo que yo sepa, pero yo no lo usaría para referirme a estos coches específicamente, ya que por mucho que el término pudiera englobarlos, no se usaría para referirse a ellos específicamente.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>Respuesta *community wiki*, siéntete libre de mejorarla. Siempre, eso sí, aportando argumentos válidos.</sup>

Cierto es que va a ser complicado encontrar un término único que los describa con la misma precisión que el original, pero podemos intentar encontrar una expresión que lo haga en la menor cantidad de palabras posible.

La propuesta actual es:

> **Deportivo *vintage* estadounidense asequible**

- El término *[deportivo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4Tpk0J8)* haría referencia a la parte de "muscle": coche con fuerza o con [garra](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IvZfWwx), un coche "dotado de una mecánica de altas prestaciones y diseñado para circular a alta velocidad".
- El término *[vintage](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vintage)* haría referencia a la parte de que son "con cierta edad, que no pueden aún catalogarse como antigüedades, y que, como los buenos vinos, se considera que han mejorado o se han revalorizado con el paso del tiempo".
- El término *estadounidense* sería simplemente por su procedencia. Aunque los coches fueran también comunes en el resto de América, las compañías que los fabricaban eran todas de Estados Unidos.
- El término *asequible* es por evitar la gama alta de precios.

Se ha hablado de sustituir *vintage* por *retro*, pero la Wikipedia nos advierte: "Cuando nos referimos a retro, se trata de objetos que evocan al pasado, pero que no deben necesariamente pertenecer a él, ni siquiera haber sido diseñados en otros tiempos, simplemente emplean la estética de otra época tratando de apelar a nuestra nostalgia." Así pues, se podría emplear pero siempre teniendo en cuenta este criterio (por ejemplo, si el coche es moderno pero imitando la estética de los 60). Según el [comentario de walen](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19564/traducci%C3%B3n-en-espa%C3%B1ol-para-muscle-cars/19566?noredirect=1#comment29384_19566), podríamos usar efectivamente *retro* o directamente eliminar el término.

Respuestas anteriores que han ido siendo mejoradas:

- Deportivo *vintage* norteamericano.
- Deportivo *vintage* americano asequible (por ser conocido en toda América y por evitar la gama alta de precios).

Comment: @walen un comentario muy constructivo. Sin embargo, la pregunta sostiene que un "deportivo" puede incluir cualquier coche de cualquier ámbito económico, mientras que los "muscle cars" al parecer evitan el rango de coches caros. Podríamos dejarlo, como indicas, en "deportivo americano", pero aún tendríamos que buscar algo que indicara este último detalle.

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo (@walen) con quitar lo de "norteamericano" porque ninguna de las marcas que se mencionan fueron creadas en ningún lugar entre México y Argentina. Son carros de compañías Estadounidenses así hoy en día se ensamblen en muchos países. EEUU no es América. Tal vez sea Norteamérica si los Mexicanos y los Canadienses no se enojan, pero América es el continente y Estados Unidos de América es solo un país donde se inventaron los _muscle cars_

Comment: @DGaleano al final entre todos me vais a marear. :D

Comment: jejej +1 por "estadounidense"

Comment: @DGaleano arreglado, respuesta _community wiki_ y quien quiera cambiarla (aportando argumentos válidos) que lo haga libremente. :D

Comment: Para mi Deportivo americano no me evoca a "muscle cars"  y el Camaro nuevo es un "muscle cars" asi que lo de vintage no es relevante

Answer (score 2):

Relacionado con mis comentarios a la respuesta de @CarlosAlejo, yo propondría **"*coupé* V8 americano"** (o cupé, si queremos evitar el galicismo). Añadiendo "clásico" por en medio, si queremos diferenciar de los *muscle car* modernos.

La inmensa mayoría de *muscle cars* eran de tipo dos puertas y con motor V8, son dos de los rasgos más característicos. Incluso hoy en día, los coches que se siguen vendiendo como *muscle car* suelen seguir ese patrón también. Otros rasgos serían un gran cubicaje (motores de 5, 6, 7 litros) y muchos caballos (entre 200 y 500 CV), pero eso serían ya explicaciones adicionales.
Además, fueron y son coches cuyo hábitat natural es América, siendo populares en el norte (México, USA) y, en menor medida, en el sur (Brasil, Argentina); resultando mucho más raro encontrarlos circulando en otros continentes como Europa o Asia.

Teniendo en cuenta el objetivo de la pregunta:

> El otro día quería explicárselo en español a alguien

*Coupé* es un término bastante conocido y debería servir para que la persona se haga una idea; V8 quizá no tanto, pero, si ese alguien no entiende aunque sea un mínimo sobre coches, será complicado igualmente explicárselo, aun existiendo un término específico.